# I want to Random Name with button Start and Stop in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Hi every body pls show me the code. when i press start i want to see random in txtfield and when press stop it record the random name.

```js
function startRandomly() {
  choices = document.getElementById("choicelist").value.split("\n");
  if (choices.length == 0) return;
  //document.getElementById("result").value = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  document.getElementById("result").value = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
}
```

```html
<form action="" onSubmit="return false;">
  <textarea id="choicelist" rows="10" cols="20">Pls input name here...</textarea>
     
   <input value="Start" onClick="startRandomly(); return false;" type="button">
            <input value="Stop" onClick="stopRandomly" type="button">
   <p>Congratulation: </p><input id="result" size="50" value="" readonly type="text">
 </form>
```

Comment: *"pls show me the code"*: you may want to hire a programmer.

Comment: pelase think of [accepting an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: if my answer helped please accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`, inside the `setInterval` you generate random numbers between `0` and the length of the array.

```js
var interval = null;
    var randomValue = null;
    var choices = [];
    function startRandomly() {
       choices = document.getElementById("choicelist").value.trim().split("\n").filter(Boolean);
        if (choices.length == 0) return;
        if (choices.length == 1) {
            randomValue = 0;
            stopRandomly();
            return;
        }
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            randomValue = getRandomInt(0, choices.length - 1);
            document.getElementById("random").innerHTML = choices[randomValue];
        }, 1);
    }

    function stopRandomly() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        if (choices.length && randomValue >= 0) {
            document.getElementById("result").value = choices[randomValue];
        }
    }

    function getRandomInt(min, max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }
```

```html
<form action="" onSubmit="return false;">
    <textarea id="choicelist" rows="10" cols="20" placeholder="Pls input name here..."></textarea>

    <input value="Start" onClick="startRandomly(); return false;" type="button">
    <input value="Stop" onClick="stopRandomly()" type="button">
    <p>Current: <span id="random"></span></p>
    <p>Congratulation: </p><input id="result" size="50" value="" readonly type="text">
</form>
```